# What is/are the difference(s) between the two following variables? (Except their names)

Tags: c

`char *s1 = "";`

`char *s2 = NULL;`

What is the difference?

Comment: Here is an analogy: https://imgur.com/Af7I80M

Comment: @Raildex Funny but not very pedagogic. In case of NULL there's no paper holder at all where you can store something.

Comment: @Lundin the holders are `s1` and `s2` respectively :)

Comment: If you think of pointers as "laser pointers" ... `s1` is **on** and pointing to a valid string; `s2` is **off** and it doesn't matter where it points to -- https://ibb.co/0Df9rZJ

Comment: By definition, a null pointer does not point to anything.  Empty strings are elements of the unbounded set of things to which null pointers do not point.

Answer (score 3):

One is pointing to the first element of an array of a single `char` element, the element being the string null-terminator character `'\0'`.

The other variable is initialized point to `NULL` which means it doesn't point anywhere, really.

---

Slightly simplified, the definition

```
char *s1 = "";
```

is kind of equivalent to

```
char private_array[1] = { '\0' };
char *s1 = &private_array[0];
```

It might seem confusing to have both a string *null* terminator, and a generic *null* pointer, but it will clear itself out with more experience.

Also note that in C all literal strings (even `""`) are not modifiable, they are in essence *read only*. That's why it's recommended to always use `const char *` to point to literal strings.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very big differnce using `""` leaves `'\0'`, whereas `NULL` leaves the pointer as `((void *)0)`.

This can be tested via dereferencing the pointer like:

*NOTE: Dereferencing the pointer means accessing its inner values or elements, which is done using `*` unary operator or `[]` operator in C/C++.*

### ""

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *s1 = "";
    printf("%d", *s1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm printing the integer representation of `*s1` because `'\0'` can't be seen on the terminal.

Ouput:

```
0
```

And program returned `0` which means `""` ends with `'\0'`.

#### NULL

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *s2 = NULL;
    printf("%d", *s2);
    return 0;
}
```

The above program printed nothing on `stdout`, but it returned `139`, which means program crashed before it exited (segmentation fault), as it was an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You can [try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn4YYvKvr).

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer leads to undefined behavior, which *may* lead to a crash. It's not guaranteed though,

Answer (score 0):

The first one points to a 0-byte and can be dereferenced but the second one points to 0 and cannot be dereferenced

Comment: *The first one points to a 0-byte* is vague: `s1` points to a 1-byte constant array with a null terminator (a byte with the value 0).  *second one points to 0* is incorrect, `s2` **is** a null pointer, it does not point to anything, and of course dereferencing it has undefined behavior.

Comment: The second one does not **point** to 0, it **is** 0, and cannot be dereferenced.